# How to download file using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

How to download a file using JavaScript *only*?

Please don't give me answer like

`"Change the`***`MIME`***`in the sever"`

or

`window.open(`***`URL`***`,"_blank")`

Because I know there are another solutions. Thanks.

**EDIT:**
The file I want to download is a `.JSON` file.

Comment: if you know there are other solutions... why are you asking?

Comment: Well, what kind of file?

Comment: If you're asking how to allow a download initiated from JavaScript while blocking all other downloads, you can't.  How is the server supposed to tell a JavaScript initiated request from a non-JavaScript one?  What state is it possible to mutate in JavaScript that cannot be spoofed by a determined user?  None, as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 9):

You can dynamically create an iframe and set its location to the URL you wish to download.

```
var f = document.createElement("iframe");
f.setAttribute("id", "theFrame");
document.body.appendChild(f);
document.getElementById("theFrame").location = 'http://www.example.com/yourfile.doc';
```

Not sure if the above works properly.  If not, try setting it by `src` instead of `location` in the last line:

```
document.getElementById("theFrame").src = 'http://www.example.com/yourfile.doc';
```

Comment: Or even more simply:  `window.location.href = 'http://www.example.com/yourfile.doc';`